# Finding angle between 2 vectors using inner product

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, angle

Consider $\mathbb{R}^3$
equipped with the inner product

$$
\langle u,v\rangle = u_1v_1 + 2u_2v_2 + 3u_3v_3
$$

Let

$$
a = \pmatrix{2 \\ 1 \\ -4} ~~~~\mbox{and}~~~~ b = \pmatrix{1 \\ -1 \\ 3}
$$

Find the angle $\theta$ between $a$ and $b$, using this inner product.

Whenever I do this I always end up getting $\cos(\theta) = -2/\sqrt{5}$

But that doesn't seem right given we're supposed to find the actual angle (without the use of calculators)

Thanks

Comment: All I can say is that you're right: $\cos(\theta)=-\frac2{\sqrt5}$.

Comment: $\theta$ is the complementary angle at $A$ in a right-angled triangle $ABC$ with $AB=1$, $BC=2$ (right angle at $B$). It's not one of the "standard angles" like $60$ degrees etc. so you always get an approximated answer.

Answer (score 1):

For you to compare your solution:
$$|a|=\sqrt{1\cdot 2^2+2\cdot 1^2+3\cdot (-4)^2}=\sqrt{54}=3\sqrt{6},\\
|b|=\sqrt{1\cdot 1^2+2\cdot (-1)^2+3\cdot 3^2}=\sqrt{30}=\sqrt{6\cdot 5},\\
a\cdot b=2\cdot 1+2\cdot 1\cdot (-1)+3\cdot (-4)\cdot 3=-36,\\
|a|\cdot |b|\cdot \cos \theta = a\cdot b \Rightarrow \cos \theta =\frac{a\cdot b}{|a|\cdot |b|}=\frac{-36}{3\sqrt{6}\cdot \sqrt{6\cdot 5}}=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are correct. What about the answer $$\theta = \cos ^{-1} ( \frac {-2}{\sqrt 5})$$

That is the actual answer.